# YUI2 equivalent of jQuery mask

Tags: jquery, mask, equivalent, yui2

I wonder if there is YUI2 equivalent of [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at this time there isn't.  See this message: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ydn-javascript/message/34571